# MS Access Ctrl + Enter for new line results in extra line breaks when exported to a text file

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I am preparing a database with many different types of fields.  One, a memo field is best organized with line breaks.  When I type the lines and use the appropriate `Ctrl + Enter` to force a line break, all looks good.

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3
```

Then I have a script that connects to a query in the database which concatenates a large string of text and memo fields together and saves the complete column into a text file.  Unfortunately this is filled with extra line breaks i.e.

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

All these extra lines are not intended or desired.
```

So to me it looks like this line break is not doing what I thought, but since this special character works behind the scene, I am not quite sure what it is doing and how I can get a single line break in both instances.

Comment: Have you tried shift-enter instead of control-enter?  (I'm not sure if this will work in Access.)

Comment: @aparente001 - I tried shift enter before I had to look up ctrl + enter, or the alternative change default enter behaviour (property field that enables direct carriage returns - which still results in two line breaks when exported to the text file.

Comment: Perhaps this will help?  http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199729-inserting-carriage-return-textbox

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks but I am not trying to concatenate several strings together externally from the memo box, if I insert a char code, it will just show up as text.